# Is there a word or phrase for this situation?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Often I see people comment on tragedies online and attempt to "deflect" it with something "more tragic."

For example, let's say that a woman in a workplace in the USA is oppressed for what she wears to work, and ends up making the rounds online. Usually I see comments such as 'Well in other parts of the world women face *x* punishment just for stepping out their front door.'

My question is, does this process of saying "*whoever* is worse off so it's not that bad" have a name? It almost resembles [strawman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) but it doesn't *quite* fit I'm sure there is a better way of phrasing it.

Comment: It's a form of "one-upmanship", but that doesn't precisely match.

Comment: Pretty close! Would like an exact match though. Seems common enough these that surely there is a term or phrase out there.

Comment: Also, overshadowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you may be looking for is a "[whataboutism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism)"  or possibly the *tu quoque* logical fallacy.

Comment: My first thought was "whataboutery" too. I think it's a better answer as it is a general term for the process, the effect of which is to minimise, trivialise, negate or deflect the original point, without actually addressing it.

Comment: Agreed - 'whataboutism' is definitely a good fit with what I was thinking. Shame it doesn't have a nice sounding term, almost sounds like a made up word haha. Thank you :)

Comment: Technically, all words are made up.  It might be best go for *the tu quoque fallacy*. There’s nothing like a bit of Latin to scare the children.

Answer (score 2):

The psychological and rhetorical concept you're looking for is [minimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimisation_(psychology)), for which there are many synonyms.

I think the best term here is that the speaker is **downplaying** the woman's struggles.